# Activity has leaked ServiceConnection on getting Google AdId in Galaxy S4

Tags: android, memory-leaks, google-play-services

I'm tring to get Google's advertising ID for my app. It works but when I test it on my Galaxy S4 (4.3). it finishs with leaking ServiceConnection error. This doesn't make Force close but print error log every time I click back button on the Activity. S4 is fresh factory reset state. It's fine on my Galaxy J5 (6.0.1)

I see the play service is out of date and AdId is null.

`W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 10084000 but found 3225130`

Any idea to resolve this issue?

code

```
public static class InitialisingTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {

    private final String TAG = InitialisingTask.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

        Context context = contexts[0];

        AdvertisingIdClient.Info idInfo = null;
        try {
            idInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException | GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "fetch Google Ads is failed. exception message=" + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (idInfo != null) {
            String adId = idInfo.getId();
            setAdId(adId);

            Log.d(TAG, "fetching Google Ads id finished. adId=" + adId);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

error log

```
02-24 00:42:59.611 24301-24301/com.company.android.sample E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
02-24 00:42:59.611 24301-24301/com.company.android.sample E/ActivityThread: Activity com.company.android.sample.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.common.zza@42b401c0 that was originally bound here
                                                                             android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.company.android.sample.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.gms.common.zza@42b401c0 that was originally bound here
                                                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:979)
                                                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:873)
                                                                                 at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1818)
                                                                                 at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1806)
                                                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:503)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzf(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                                                 at com.skb.nads.internal.sdk.v1.AdSdk$1.run(AdSdk.java:115)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `ContextWrapper` to capture leaked `ServiceConnection`.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

        Context context = contexts[0];

        final List<ServiceConnection> leakableServiceList = new ArrayList<>(1);
        try {
            ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(context) {
                @Override
                public boolean bindService(Intent service, ServiceConnection conn, int flags) {
                    if ("com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.service.START".equals(service.getAction())
                            && "com.google.android.gms".equals(service.getPackage())) {
                        leakableServiceList.add(conn);
                    }
                    return super.bindService(service, conn, flags);
                }
            };
            AdvertisingIdClient.setShouldSkipGmsCoreVersionCheck(true);
            AdvertisingIdClient.Info idInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(contextWrapper);
            if (idInfo != null) {
                String adId = idInfo.getId();
                setAdId(adId);
                Log.d(TAG, "fetching Google Ads id finished. adId=" + adId);
            }
            // https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException | GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "fetch Google Ads is failed. exception message=" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            for (ServiceConnection conn: leakableServiceList) {
                try {
                    context.unbindService(conn);
                    Log.w(TAG, "Oh! leaking service connection is detected and fixed.");
                } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // OK - already unbind and not leaked!
                } catch(Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "something terrible happens", t);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```